# Вишнёвый сад

Tags: ударение

Чехов писал: "Пьеса называется не "ВИшневый сад", а "Вишнёвый..." - символ чистоты, прекрасного и духовного. "ВИшневый" же - всё на продажу. Услышьте же, ради Бога, разницу в ударениях, дорогой  вы мой!"

А можем ли мы услышать и понять разницу в ударениях? Что в данном случае имел в виду наш известный русский писатель?

ПОЯСНЕНИЕ

Теперь в словарях дается: вишнёвый (вИшневый - устар!), но слИвовый. В трехсложных прилагательных ударение может падать на любой слог, значит, выбор делается по смыслу, три разных смысла: а) гЕлевый, мАчтовый, б) оптОвый, рискОвый, кленОвый, почтОвый, в) суповОй, правовОй, исковОй, биржевОй.

В некоторых случаях допускаются варианты: джИнсовый и джинсОвый, ценовОй и цЕновый, ножевОй и ножОвый, языковОй и языкОвый, вЕтреный и ветрянОй, домОвый и домовОй, лаврОвый и лАвровый. Анализ именно этих слов мог бы  установить смысловую разницу трех вариантов ударений.

Попытки объяснить выбор ударения путем анализа акцентных групп исходных существительных не очень удачен: на каждое правило иногда получается столько же исключений.

Answer (score 3):

По-моему, всё ясно, по Станиславскому:«Ви́шневый сад» - это деловой, коммерческий сад, приносящий доход. Такой сад нужен и теперь. Но «Вишнёвый сад» дохода не приносит, он хранит в себе и в своей цветущей белизне поэзию былой барской жизни. Такой сад растет и цветет для прихоти, для глаз избалованных эстетов. Жаль уничтожать его, а надо, так как процесс экономического развития страны требует этого".

ВИшневый-акцент на дереве, относительное прилагательное, вишнёвый -качественное, обозначает цвет, а у Чехова - цветущие деревья, их цвет-бело-вишнёво-розовый, очень красивый. У Чехова вишнЁвый сад – прекрасное творение природы и рук человеческих. О цветущем вишневом саде сказано в описании обстановки первого действия. О его красоте говорят уже в начале пьесы. Тут же Гаев сообщает, что сад их упоминается в «Энциклопедическом словаре» . «Если во всей губернии есть что-нибудь интересное, – говорит Любовь Андреевна, – даже замечательное, так это наш вишневый сад» . Распахнув окна в сад, Любовь Андреевна восклицает: «Какой изумительный сад! Белые массы цветов, голубое небо… »

Однако сад в пьесе - это и символ, причем весьма многозначный. Для Любови Андреевны он неразрывно связан с воспоминанием о ее детстве, о безвременно утраченной чистоте и молодости, о времени, когда она была так беззаботна и счастлива. Была такой, какова сегодня ее дочь Аня. Недаром же Гаев говорит Ане сразу при встрече: «Как ты похожа на свою мать! Ты, Люба, в ее годы была точно такая» .

Вот об этом прекрасном прошлом и вспоминает Раневская, глядя через распахнутое окно детской комнаты на цветущий сад: «О, мое детство, чистота моя! В этой детской я спала, глядела оттуда на сад, счастье просыпалось вместе со мною каждое утро, и тогда он был точно таким, ничто не изменилось. Весь, весь белый! О, сад мой! После темной ненастной осени и холодной зимы опять ты молод, полон счастья, ангелы небесные не покинули тебя… »

Но вишневый сад не только символ чистоты и молодости. Это и хозяйственная основа имения в его прошлом, неразрывно связанная с крепостным рабством. «Подумайте, Аня, – говорит Петя, – ваш дед, прадед и все ваши предки были крепостники, владевшие живыми душами, и неужели с каждой ветки в саду, с каждого ствола не глядят на вас человеческие существа, неужели вы не слышите их голосов… » Каких голосов? Для читателей и зрителей Чехова не было сомнения, что речь здесь шла о голосах замученных, засеченных в этом саду крепостных рабах.

Так, с образом вишневого сада оказываются связаны размышления о социальном укладе русской жизни. Прежде всего, о ее прошлом укладе. Но тут же – и о настоящем. Имение в долгах, как его сохранить, как спасти прекрасный сад? И выясняется, что сделать это невозможно, не погубив его красоты.Лопахин сделал выбор в соответствии с идеей:время бывших хозяев прошло, настоящий хозяин - деловой человек, но о красоте не заботится, время за будущими хозяевами, заботящимися и о доходах, и о красоте.

Comment: Вишнёвый сад как образ - это замечательно. Но тогда получается, что  Чехов говорит о частном случае, о метафоре. А как быть с общей проблемой? Какие оттенки смысла мы выражаем, смещая ударение на суффикс или на окончание? Ведь обычно прилагательные с суффиксом ОВ/ЕВ являются относительными, а не качественными.

Comment: И вот что еще интересно: во времена Чехова какое ударение считалось правильным? Может быть, метафора основана  на нестандартной фонетике слова?

Comment: @София я постарался ответить по сути на все ваши вопросы.

Comment: В воспоминаниях Чехова есть указание на то, что поначалу он произносил вИшневый,видно, это был переходный период, связанный с употреблением буквы Ё, которая стала писаться после мягких согласных, но старые интеллигенты, к которым Чехов относится,её избегали,"вишнёвый" вторично и воспринималось только в значении "цвет", как переносное(как вишня)- отсюда качественные и относительные прилагательные. Тонко чувствующие язык и сейчас видят разницу, а основная часть населения быстро привыкла к новому произношению без различия смысла.Исконный смысл многих слов нами потерян, в 19 веке ещё сохранялся.

Comment: А  причём  здесь  буква  Ё,  она  ведь  только  обозначила  произношение.  Допустим,  что  Чехов  избегал  эту  букву,  а  звук  он  тоже  избегал ?  Как  он  в  этом  случае  смыслы  различал ?   Вот  интересно :  вишневый  цвет - это  цветы  вишни ( дерева ),  вишнёвый  цвет  -  это  спелой  ягоды  вишни,  а  дерево  вишни  как  будет:  вишнёвое  или  вИшневое ?  Сад  ведь  из  деревьев  состоит.  Мне  кажется,  что  как  метафора   "вишнёвый  сад"  будет  работать  при  любом  ударении  -  метафоры  тоже  многозначны.

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос уже что называется "застрял в ушах".

Словари не передают всей ситуации с устаревшими ударениями. 
Во времена Чехова было два варианта ударения, они относились к разным значениям. 
"ВИшневый" означало относящийся к вишне (ягоде-костянке), "вишнёвый" - к цвету. Видимо, Чехов хотел своей фразой подчеркнуть, что в названии обыгрывается эта ситуация и про сад говорится не применительно к вишням-ягодах, а о цветущем саде - символе.

С тех пор ударение вИшневый устарело (не под влиянием ли самого Чехова???) и передать тонкость исходного чеховского названия стало невозможным.

Нечто подобное имело место, например, для сливы: слИвовый и сливОвый предположительно различались по значению. Но тут победило другое ударение: слИвовый

Comment: Вишнёвый цвет - это розово-белый? Или малиново-бордовый? Или вишневый цвет - это цветы вишни? ПРИМЕРЫ. "И в это лето на дней десять раньше обычного стал опадать вишневый цвет (А. Соболь). "Спелая ягода темнеет и получает свой собственный, вишневый цвет" (С. Аксаков). "Вишневый цвет тебе, кажется, больше будет идти в этом уборе" (Н. Лесков). "Это была северная заря, вся малиново-блестящая, как в елочных игрушках" (М. Пришвин). "Высокая, статная, как лебедка, с яблочным румянцем на белом, как вишневый цвет, лице" (Б. Садовской).

Comment: Почему победило? И сейчас слИвовое варенье(из слив), но цвет сливОвый(как у слив), просто появилось более точное слово фиолетовый, оно заменило название цвета, слово ушло из употребления, но кто-то его ещё употребляет.

Comment: Вероятно,  вишнёвый - это красно-бордовый цвет. Если речь шла о белом цвете, то надо было употреблять сравнение: белый, как вишневый цвет (вишнёвое цветение). Тогда вишнёвый сад во времена Чехова - это цветущий сад, то есть белый, как вишнёвый цвет.

Comment: >но цвет сливОвый(как у слив),  

Лет двадцать назад я бы согласился. Сейчас словари в массе дают как устаревшее или вовсе исключают.   
http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%F1%EB%E8%E2%EE%E2%FB%E9&all=x    
  
Но я не хотел бы переключаться на сливу. Этот пример - аналогия с тем, как было в отношении вишни при Чехове.

Comment: Красно-бордовый  -  это  свекольный ( цвет  сваренной  свёклы ).